# What's the pythonic way to repeat first and last element of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-manipulation

If I have a list like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` what's considered a more *pythonic* way (if this is not already it) to repeat the first and last elements only and obtain `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]`?

What I'm doing right now is:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [a[0], *a, a[-1]]
```

Comment: Depend how you save the `specification` os what number should doubled, tripled, ..

Comment: How about `[a[0]] + a + [a[-1]]`?

Comment: For long lists (~1M), your solution is the fastest. Stick to it.

Comment: It is not fair to change your question on the fly. Clearly, the original problem and the new problem call for quite different solutions.

Comment: Ok, I'll create a new question for that, sorry

Answer (score 4):

I would do the following, which simply glues together three separate lists:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[:1] + a + a[-1:]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Is this considered more pythonic? I mean, mine is quite explicit, it literally says "I'm creating a list containing the first element of a, every element of a and the last element of a" while using concatenation it says "I'm concatenating a list containing only the first element of a, the list a itself and a list containing only the last element of a" which is a little more convoluted, i guess. Also, performance wise, which is faster?

Comment: There is no objective measure of "pythonic". Subjectively, I find this approach easy to read and to understand, and it works only on lists and sub-lists, rather than trying to construct a new list from a single element (i.e. `a[:1]` instead of `[a[0]]`). In terms of performance, you should measure the approaches you are offered and work out what is best for your use case. If you need to extend repetition beyond one element, note that this approach is very easy to adapt.

Comment: I see your point, indeed extending the problem with more than 2 indexes to repeat (or repeating more than twice) would be easier with only lists and sublists. I'll investigate more about performance, thank you